# How to select how many columns have the same value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have query that selects goes something like this:

```
        $query   = "SELECT members.*
      FROM members 
      JOIN $nombre
      ON members.member_ID=$nombre.friends";
 $result   = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 $number   =  mysql_num_rows($result);
 $i    = 0;

 while($msg  =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {

  //store data in arrays
  $peer_id[$i]   = $msg['member_ID'];
  $peer_state[$i]   = $msg['home_state'];
  $pro_political_views[$i]        = $msg['political_views'];
  $peer_district[$i]  = $msg['district'];
  $peer_first[$i]   = $msg['first_name'];
  $peer_last[$i]   = $msg['last_name'];
  $peer_issue[$i]   = $msg['first_issue'];
  $peer_second[$i]          = $msg['second_issue'];
  $peer_third[$i]   = $msg['third_issue'];
  $peer_stand[$i]   = $msg['iStand'];
  $peer_mail[$i]   = $msg['email'];
  $peer_pic[$i]   = $msg['photo'];

  ++$i;

 }
```

What this essentially does is get all the values from columns in the rows in the members from the members table where the `member_ID` is present in the `$nombre` table.

In the members table, there are two columns called "`state`" and "`district`". I want to make it so that php could tell me how many different values there are in the state and district columns for this query.

So, how could I go about writing a query or use php to tell how many how many peers are from a given state. I don't want to have to query the db once for each of the fifty states because that would take way too much time for the page to load. So, is there an efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use two queries, like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT members.state
FROM members 
JOIN $nombre
ON members.member_ID=$nombre.friends
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT members.district
FROM members 
JOIN $nombre
ON members.member_ID=$nombre.friends
```

This will give you all of the unique states and districts back, which you can use or count or whatever.

Alternatively, add this somewhere in your `while` loop:

```
$all_states[$msg['state']] = 1;
$all_districts[$msg['district']] = 1;
```

Then, after the loop you can:

```
$state_count = count($all_states);
$district_count = count($all_districts);
```

The query approach would be faster by itself (assuming an index on the `state` and `district` columns), but the latter approach will be faster if you are already executing this loop anyway.

**EDIT:** To count unique districts in each state, replace

```
$all_districts[$msg['district']] = 1;
```

with something like

```
$all_districts[$msg['state'] . '--' . $msg['district']] = 1;
```

This will include the state in the array key too, and the `count()` call later will return all of the unique district-state combinations.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. But, if I wanted to take this a step further and find out how many of the district for each state were distinct, how would I do that?

Comment: For example, district 1 of New York is different than district 1 of california. how would i get php to recognize the the values of the districts are only unique if the district AND the state are the same?

Comment: Cool. thanks a bunch. Could I use the SELECT DISTINCT query to display all of the states for which it's present in the database? If a state is present in more than one row, I only want it to appear once...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what SELECT DISTINCT does.  It selects only distinct result sets.  So to replicate what you wanted for districts, you would "SELECT DISTINCT members.state, members.district FROM ...", which will select only one of each distinct state-district pair present in the database.

Answer (score 1):

> ...to tell how many how many peers are
>   from a given state

For states:

```
SELECT state, COUNT(m.member_ID) cnt
FROM members m
  JOIN $nombre n ON m.member_ID=n.friends
GROUP BY state
```

and for districts:

```
SELECT 'district', COUNT(m.member_ID) cnt
FROM members m
  JOIN $nombre n ON m.member_ID=n.friends
GROUP BY 'district'
```

This queries returns distinct values for states and districts and count of peers from them

Answer (score 0):

you can save the district in additional  array like

```
$district[] =  $msg['district'];
```

after the loop `print_r` using a function [array_count_values](http://php.net/array_count_values)

```
print_r(array_count_values($district));
```

Comment: This will return how many rows were processed, not how many rows had the same district.

Comment: why ? using array count values return how many you have in the array for each value

Comment: It will return how many values you have.  It does not care if some of those values are the same.